# Powershell incrementing name and execute cmdline

Tags: windows, powershell, exchange-server, increment

I'm trying to write a powershell script that will create outlook logs (using NETMON) from the local client to the exchange server.  The problem is the file name is not incrementing correctly.  I found this incrementing script online and i understand the logic (kinda).  Am i using the right way to initialize the counter?  It isn't renaming the file correctly.  It gives the 2nd file just a _ then the 3rd file gets a _2 then after that it stops renaming files.

ALSO is invoke-expression waiting for my cmd to exit or will it just go to the next step of $count-- ?

```
#Directory to complete script in
$path = "c:\Outlook_Logs\" 
cd $path
$cmdline = "Nmcap.exe /network * /captureipv4.address==X.X.X.X /file :\outlook_logs\client_$count.chn:100MB"

#Writes out number of files in directory to console
$count = (get-childitem $path -name).count
Write-Host "Number of Files: $count"

#Sorts items by decsending order
$items = Get-ChildItem | Sort Extension -desc 

#Deletes oldest file by file extension number
del $items[0]

#Copy file from original directory to backup directory
Copy-Item c:\Outlook_Logs\* c:\Outlook_Logs_Temp\

#Sorts items by decsending order
$items = Get-ChildItem | Sort Extension -desc

#Renames files in quotes after NewName argument
$items | ForEach-Object  -begin { $count= (get-childitem $path -name).count }  -process { rename-    item $_ -NewName "client_$count.cap";Invoke-Expression "$cmdline"; $count-- }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to increment the names yourself. chn captures files are created and names incrementally automatically when they reach the size specified after the colon.

What happens when you lower the size to 1MB and execute the command?

Comment: when i run the cmd twice it just overwrites it the previous file.  It's not acting as as you stated...

Comment: Nmcap.exe /network * /capture ipv4.address==X.X.X.X /file c:\outlook_logs\client.chn:1MB

Comment: I don't think it remembers where it stopped. Once you rerun it will starts all over again. If you want to increment it yourself you need to use a .cap extension

Comment: i think you are right because i have to hit ctrl+c to exit.  I tried with a .cap and it's still not working.  I'll find another wat to count, possibly a do-while so we can take it from there.  I'll let you know if i have any luck thanks for your help